# Is MySQL Clustering a viable option for a DB expecting 5TB of data in 5 years?

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster, high-availability, mysql-cluster

We plan to implement MySQL Clustering.The database should support 5 years of data and expected data/year is 1TB.
When we created a test enviornment with the DB size as 200GB, NDB Cluster took more than 2 hours to restart.

Is MySQL Clustering a viable option for an application that expects 5TB of data in 5 years, if yes, could you please guide on the suggested architecture and configuration for such a setup.

Answer (score 3):

currently the maximum data set size is around 3TB, if you are using all in-memory data.
You can increase that if you use disk-based tables

MySQL Cluster also has very flexible replication to external storage engines, ie to InnoDB, so many users manage their "hot" data in cluster, then replicate "colder / aged" data to innodb.

There is a blog describing how to configure this here:
http://johanandersson.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/ha-mysql-write-scaling-using-cluster-to.html

Answer (score 1):

You should read these posts and analyze what options to choose:

- [High Availability and Scalability](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ha-overview.html)
- [A Summary of Scaling Options for MySQL](http://www.oshyn.com/_blog/General/post/A_Summary_of_Scaling_Options_for_MySQL/)
- [Where Would I Use MySQL Cluster?](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/where_would_i_use_mysql)

Also there are similar questions asked here:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/305024/is-it-possible-to-managing-20-tb-data-using-mysql
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850307/can-mysql-cluster-handle-a-terabyte-database